# Can an iPad (3rd gen) run solo with an Airport Express

Tags: ipad, wifi, router, pc

My folks are using a PC running WinXP to control a non-Apple wifi-router. The PC crashes often, bringing down with it the wifi network. They no longer actually use the PC, just the iPad, but they keep the PC to control the router.

If I replace their router with an Apple Airport Express, can I then discard the PC and control the router solely from the iPad? Could an iPad control a non-Apple wifi-router?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the correlation between the PC crashing and it bringing down the WiFi network, can you explain a bit more about this non-Apple router and how it integrates into the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited since I misread the question*

You can definitely set up and control any Apple router that supports 802.11n from an iPad only. Apple has an [iOS app just for that purpose](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airport-utility/id427276530?mt=8).

However if you want to save some money, or possible use the existing router, that may be an option too. Almost all routers these days have web interfaces, so an iPad can manage *most* routers. However there are some routers that require a PC app to manage, typically older ones.

Chances are they'll be fine, but you'll first want to check what kind of router it is, then have a quick look at the manufacturer's page to figure out if it has a web interface or not. If it does, you'll probably want to figure out the IP (typically `192.168.1.1` or `192.168.0.1`) and bookmark that for your parents.

It is a bit troubling that the router crashes when the PC crashes - sounds like something's not quite right there, so definitely check that out.

Comment: Any _modern_ Apple router.

Comment: Is there any way for me to remotely access 192.168.1.1 (or whichever IP it actually is) on my parents' router?

Comment: It depends on the router software. Some offer remote access options, others don't. If you have a router that supports 3rd party firmware like [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) or [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/), that's your best bet of getting remote access, but it's very dependent on what router you have. Apple's Airport routers [support remote management from another Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3486) via Back to My Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Airport Express can be controlled from an iPad via [Airport Utility](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/airport-dienstprogramm/id427276530?mt=8). The functionality might be a bit less than the one offered by the PC/OS X version of the utility but should be good enough for a simple home network.

Comment: If you have the full Mac/Windows version of the configuration utility, you can set up the router and the iPad can tweak what it can without messing up the other settings.